# Syntax coloring only works inside a particular directory

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, vim8

I have no idea what I did but syntax coloring only works when I open files with vim started inside a particular top level path (e.g. `/Users/name/Source/git-repository/`). If I open the same files when Vim starts from anywhere else syntax is off and I cannot turn it on.

Neovim reads from the same `.vimrc` and seems unaffected.

`.vimrc` just has `colorscheme name`.

I tried deleting `.viminfo`, `.vim/` and it did not fix anything.

Comment: What is the filetype of the file you open ``:set ft?``?  I'm interested to know the result of that command in both situations

Comment: In both situations I open a Typescript file and it says `filetype=typescript`.

Comment: `:color blue` or any other theme does not fail but does nothing, outside of the particular directory.

Comment: Check if you have any views files laying around… check `autocmd` for odd-looking things… cf. [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)